# $scope methods not recognized from table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, html-table

I'm binding an array through a form using **ng-repeat**. Here is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
   <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names">
         <td><textarea placeholder="New Name" ng-model="x.name" name="" ></textarea></td>
         <td><button style="background:#f00;" ng-click="removeChoice(x)">-</button></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
.controller('TerrItemCtrl', function($scope){
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addAddress.html', {
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'animated bounceInDown',
   hideDelay: 920
}).then(function (modal) {
   $scope.names = [{ 'id': 'name1'}];
   $scope.modal = modal;
   $scope.modal.show();
});
$scope.removeChoice = function (x) {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.names; i++) {
        if ($scope.names[i].id === x.id) {
            $scope.names.splice(i);
            break;
        }
    }
};
});
```

I have a **$scope.removeChoice** function in the controller of this form the html can't find it. I believe it's because of the array I'm using but this is the only way I've managed to put the (-) button on the right of the input tag. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: Please add your controller code.

Comment: Not an answer, but should your `data-ng-repeat` not be on the `<tr>` element instead?  The above will result in multiple `<tbody>`'s ...

Comment: You are suppose to use `$index` and then `Collection.splice(INDEX,1)`

Comment: Firstly remove ng-repeat from table tag and add it to tr tags as in you're making multple table's in HTML.

Comment: @Rayon, the code is perfectly fine,`removeChoice()` should be called with the `x` value as param. There must be something going on in the controller ...

Comment: @davidkonrad — I am also talking about controller.. To identify element to be removed, you are suppose to access it using `$index`

Comment: It suppose to be like this  $scope.names.splice(i,1);

Comment: Show us the controller code that contains the variable `names`

Comment: Guys the controller is fine..I'm calling someother methods they are called just fine..Only the one at the table doesn't get called

Comment: Your code seems correct. That is why we are asking about the controller. Maybe you are using another controller than the one defining `names`. Maybe the scope of your `ng-controller=""TerrItemCtrl` is already closed. Does the function is even reached ? Try to add `debugger` on the first line

Comment: @Rayon I  am able to locate the item that should be deleted when I don't use the table tag...It's this that causes the trouble...I'm asking if there is any that I can bypass the problem without having to abandon the table tag

Comment: `array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)` ==> _"howmany Required. The number of items to be removed. If set to 0, no items will be removed"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TerrItemCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["a", "b", "c"];

  $scope.removeChoice = function(index) {
    $scope.names.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TerrItemCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>
        <textarea placeholder="New Name" ng-model="x" name=""></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button style="background:#f00;" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha Yours is using `ng-repeat` inside the `table` tag

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.names = ["a", "b", "c"];

  $scope.removeChoice = function(x) {
    $scope.names.splice(x, 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>
          <textarea placeholder="New Name" ng-model="x" name=""></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background:#f00;" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` induces a new scope. Hence to access the parent you've to use `$parent.someMethodInParentScope()`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.names = ["a", "b", "c"];

  $scope.removeChoice = function(x) {
    $scope.names.splice(x,1);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    <table data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea placeholder="New Name" ng-model="x" name=""></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background:#f00;" ng-click="$parent.removeChoice($index)">-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

This may not be evident from ng-repeat's docs. You've to check the docs for `$rootScope`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

```
.controller('TerrItemCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addAddress.html', {
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'animated bounceInDown',
   hideDelay: 920
}).then(function (modal) {
   $scope.names = [{ 'id': 'name1'}];
   $scope.modal = modal;
   $scope.modal.show();
});
$scope.removeChoice = function (x) {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.names; i++) {
        if ($scope.names[i].id === x.id) {
            $scope.names.splice(i);
            break;
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.controller('TerrItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

Should try this Syntax pass the scope through as an array as well as in your function. The problem might be when the function is executing it doesn't pass the scope variable within the execution-able context.